# Klockwork finding (Buffer overflow)

Tags: c++, indexoutofboundsexception, static-analysis, klocwork

I have the following code

```
enum class LoggerType
{
    ASCII,           
    BINARY_1,          
    TEXT,   
    BINARY_2, 
    NUM_OF_TYPE
};

Logger* Logger::GetInstance(
    LoggerType type)
{
    static Logger* pLogger[4] =
    {
        new Logger(LoggerType::ASCII),
        new Logger(LoggerType::BINARY_1),
        new Logger(LoggerType::TEXT),
        new Logger(LoggerType::BINARY_2)
    };
    
    return pLogger[static_cast<UINT8>(type)];
}
```

And Klockwork tells me

```
Array 'pLogger' of size 2 may use index value(s) 2
```

Is there a real problem here? If so kindly let knows how can deal this problem.
Should I add some protection for "static_cast(type)"? Thanks a lot

** Following is what I guess the issue **
Because we have 5 LoggerType, KW may think it is possible to access out of bound even we don`t. So we have to add some protection here,

```
Logger* pReturnLogger = NULL;

if (static_cast<UINT8>(type) < static_cast<UINT8>(LoggerType::NUM_OF_TYPE))
{
    pReturnLogger = pLogger[static_cast<UINT8>(type)];
}
return pReturnLogger;
```

Comment: It is not a C code.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks,, let me change the tag